# Most popular Chinese given names

Tags: names

Are there any lists of the most popular Chinese given names, either in romanization or characters? http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2020-01/20/c_138721082.htm is an announcement of "the top 10 most popular full names [e.g., 张伟] and the top 50 most popular characters used in given names of 2019", but I'm wondering if there's a fuller list of common given names (not just individual characters, unless the individual characters happen to be common given names). I'm aware that Chinese first names are often built from scratch from one or two characters, but it would still be interesting to see if any names tend to be more common.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have such a list for all Chinese name user, however I can find such a list for Chinese user in Taiwan. You can find it in [Dept. of Household Registration. Ministry of Interior.](https://www.ris.gov.tw/app/portal/241) in Taiwan. You can find a section called 全國姓名統計分析. There are data for several years. One of them is [全國姓名統計分析](https://www.ris.gov.tw/documents/data/5/2/107namestat.pdf), you can find such a list for males and females in pages 266, 267 of 376 of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of Chinese Names listed in below webpage.
And there are informations of getting a good Chinese names.

https://www.xingming.com/qmyz/3956.html